# How can i start two Coroutines jobs using the result of previous job being excuted?

Tags: android, multithreading, firebase-realtime-database, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

I have to start two Coroutines jobs using the result of previous job. I tried async with job.await() method but its not working. Here is my code

```
 CoroutineScope(IO).launch {  
        val job  = async {
            val cartList = mutableListOf<Basket>()
            databaseReference.child("Cart").child("Anonymous")
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
                    override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

                    }

                    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                            for (data in dataSnapshot.children) {
                                val cart = data.getValue(Basket::class.java)
                                cartList.add(cart!!)  //I'm getting this thing
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
            cartList  // But it is returning zero, Why??
        }.await()

        val job2 = async { 
            for(result in job){} 
        }

      val job3 = async { 
            for(result in job){} 
        }
}
```

But every time i call this method it gives 0. Why it is happening like this,
when I'm able to get data from Firebase Database. Can anybody tell me, what's wrong here..

Edited:

```
   val job = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
   val data = callbackFlow<List<Basket>>      
  {           
    databaseReference.child("Cart").child("Anonymous")                                  
    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : 
    ValueEventListener {   

 override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

                            }

                            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                                    val cartList = mutableListOf<Basket>()
                                    for (data in dataSnapshot.children) {
                                        val cart = data.getValue(Basket::class.java)
                                        cartList.add(cart!!)  //I'm getting this thing
                                    }
                                    offer(cartList)
                                    channel.close()
                                }
                            }
                        })
                    awaitClose()
                }.single()
                data
            }

  val job2 = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val data = callbackFlow<List<Items>> {
                val itemsList = mutableListOf<Items>()
                for (items in job) {
                    databaseReference.child("Items").child(items.itemsId!!)
                        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
                            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

                            }

                            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                                    val item = dataSnapshot.getValue(Items::class.java)
                                    itemsList.add(item!!)
                                    offer(itemsList) // exception here because channel is closed.
                                }
                            }
                        })
                }
                channel.close()  // here channel is closed 
                awaitClose()
            }.single()
            data
        }

        val job3 = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val data = callbackFlow<List<Pair<String, String>>> {
                val priceList = mutableListOf<Pair<String, String>>()
                for (weights in job) {
                    databaseReference.child("Quantities").child(weights.itemsId!!)
                        .child(weights.itemWeight!!)
                        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
                            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

                            }

                            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                                    val key = dataSnapshot.key
                                    val value = dataSnapshot.value as String
                                    val myPair = Pair(key!!, value)
                                    priceList.add(myPair)
                                    offer(priceList)
                                }
                            }
                        })
                }
                channel.close()
                awaitClose()
            }.single()
            data
    }
}

if(job2.isNotEmpty() && job3.isNotEmpty()){
          val myCartList = mutableListOf<Cart>()
          for((counter, cartItem) in job2.withIndex()){
              val quantityPair  = job3[counter]
              val cart = Cart(cartItem.id!!,cartItem.url!!,cartItem.name!!,quantityPair.first,quantityPair.second)
              myCartList.add(cart)
          }
          _cartData.value = myCartList
      }
  }
```

I used this way but it's not working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're dealing with callbacks here. By the time `cartList` is returned, `onDataChanged` hasn't been called so the list is empty. I would use a Flow built with `callbackFlow` builder in this case. Something like this:

- **Flow approach**

Add this Flow as a member variable.

```
val myFlow = callbackFlow<List<Basket>> {
    databaseReference.child("Cart").child("Anonymous")
        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

            }

            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    val cartList = mutableListOf<Basket>()
                    for (data in dataSnapshot.children) {
                        val cart = data.getValue(Basket::class.java)
                        cartList.add(cart!!)  //I'm getting this thing
                    }
                    offer(cartList)
                    channel.close()
                }
            }
        })
    awaitClose()
}
```

Consume the Flow calling this method when you require:

```
fun getBasketList() = myScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {//Dispatchers.IO because I assume you're doing something meaningful with it inside async blocks
    val basketList = myFlow.single()
    val job2 = async {
        for(result in basketList){}
    }

    val job3 = async {
        for(result in basketList){}
    }
}
```

PS: Don't forget to make the request or you won't get anything from the Flow.

---

**Edit 1**

- **`suspendCancellableCoroutine` approach**

Add this method to you class:

```
suspend fun getBasketList(): List<Basket> = suspendCancellableCoroutine { continuation ->
    databaseReference.child("Cart").child("Anonymous")
        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                continuation.resumeWithException(p0)
            }

            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    val cartList = mutableListOf<Basket>()
                    for (data in dataSnapshot.children) {
                        val cart = data.getValue(Basket::class.java)
                        cartList.add(cart!!)  //I'm getting this thing
                    }
                    continuation.resume(cartList)
                }
            }
        })

    //MAKE YOUR REQUEST RIGHT HERE
}
```

Also add this method which will call the previous one to start the request:

```
fun requestBasketList() = myScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    val basketList = getBasketList()
    val job2 = async {
        for(result in basketList ){}
    }

    val job3 = async {
        for(result in basketList ){}
    }
}
```

---

**Edit 2**

If you need to keep working with the basket list and make other requests for each item in it you can do something like this:

```
val basketList = getBasketList().single()
val cartList = mutableListOf<Cart>()
val jobs = basketList.map {
    launch {
        val result = //MAKE YOUR FIREBASE REQUEST HERE
        val cart = // Work with 'result' and make your transformations here
        cartList.add(cart)
    }
}
jobs.joinAll()
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214039/discussion-on-answer-by-glenn-sandoval-how-can-i-start-two-coroutines-jobs-using).